# Atom : how to create its own custom commands by project?

Tags: atom-editor

I like to create custom command for a project. I'd like to have specific commands by project (not global). (Ex: compile, prettify, generate ...)
I'm pretty sure it's possible thru packages : but which one ?

best solution : i'd like to create a file in my project, which contains commands easily callable thru atom editor ...